# Python: Apply a custom function to multiple specified columns in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a function that i have created which looks for missing values in a dataframe.
Missing values can take on many forms in our dataset and this toy function below handles it
My question is around applying this function.
I have a list of columns (20 or so) that i would like to apply the same function to.
Below is the setup for one column

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris

# Create a sample dataset
iris = load_iris()

df = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                 columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])
df['species'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(iris.target, iris.target_names)

# Here we replace all values of setosa with 'missing_value'
df = df.applymap(lambda x: 'missing_value' if x == 'setosa' else x)

# Here we want to create a flag for the missing values
def add_missing_value_flags(mydf, column):
    
    # Generate the new column name
    new_col = "missing_" + column
    
    # Create flags where the data is missing
    # that has put in a holder to represent a missing value
    mydf[new_col]= np.where(mydf[column] == 'missing_value', True,
                            np.where(mydf[column] == '', True,
                            np.where(mydf[column] == 'N/A', True,  
                            np.where(mydf[column] == 'N\A', True, 
                            np.where(mydf[column] == 'NA', True,
                            np.where(mydf[column] == 'N.A.', True,
                            np.where(mydf[column] == 'NONE', True,
                            np.where(mydf[column] == '.', True, 
                            np.where(mydf[column].str.len() == 1, True, 
                            np.where(mydf[column] == '..', True, False))))))))))
    
    return(mydf)


add_missing_value_flags(df, 'species')

     sepal length (cm)  sepal width (cm)  ...        species  missing_species
0                  5.1               3.5  ...  missing_value             True
1                  4.9               3.0  ...  missing_value             True
2                  4.7               3.2  ...  missing_value             True
3                  4.6               3.1  ...  missing_value             True
4                  5.0               3.6  ...  missing_value             True
..                 ...               ...  ...            ...              ...
145                6.7               3.0  ...      virginica            False
146                6.3               2.5  ...      virginica            False
147                6.5               3.0  ...      virginica            False
148                6.2               3.4  ...      virginica            False
149                5.9               3.0  ...      virginica            False
```

**Is there a method in python where I can apply my function to the rest of my columns similiar to:** `mydf[mydf.columns[mydf.columns.str.contains('species|plant|earth')]].apply...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# Create a sample dataset
iris = load_iris()

df = pd.DataFrame(data= np.c_[iris['data'], iris['target']],
                 columns= iris['feature_names'] + ['target'])
df['species'] = pd.Categorical.from_codes(iris.target, iris.target_names)

# Here we replace all values of setosa with 'missing_value'
df = df.applymap(lambda x: 'missing_value' if x == 'setosa' else x)


def function_to_apply(series):
    if not re.match("missing_", series.name):
        new_column_name = "missing_"+series.name
        new_column_values = series.isin([
            'missing_value', '', 'N/A', 'N\A',
            'NA', 'N.A.', 'NONE', '.', '..'
        ])
        try:
            new_column_values = new_column_values | (series.str.len()==1)
        except AttributeError:
            pass
        df[new_column_name] = new_column_values
    return
```

I wrote `function_to_apply` in order to modify inplace `df` and I set the return value = `None`, so:

```
df.apply(function_to_apply)
#RETURNS
#sepal length (cm)    None
#sepal width (cm)     None
#petal length (cm)    None
#petal width (cm)     None
#target               None
#species              None
#dtype: object
```

However, by applying this function, you have added columns to `df`:
[image: modified df]

I know is not the cleanest solution, but it works and it is relatively fast.

P.S. you need to `import re` in addition to the other libraries to run this code.

Comment: Hi Salvatore, I took the function you provided and changed it slightly and am now able to run the following where I can manually add the columns I am interested in using something like `df[df.columns[df.columns.str.contains('species')]].apply(lambda x: add_missing_value_flags(x))`. Thank you for your help. I would never have solved it without your code

Answer (score 1):

If you want to apply this function to all your columns you can do that within a list comprehension:

```py
[add_missing_value_flags(df, column) for column in df.columns]
```

The resulting dataframe (`df`) will contain the columns you need.

Note that for running this, you will need to adapt your function `add_missing_value_flags` slightly. Most of the columns in your dataframe do not contain string data. With the following version the list comprehension above will work:

```py
def add_missing_value_flags(mydf, column):

    # Generate the new column name
    new_col = "missing_" + column

    # Create flags where the data is missing or there is a shipper name
    # that has put in a holder to represent a missing value

    # convert values to strings before running string comparison
    filtered_df = mydf[column].astype(str)

    mydf[new_col]= np.where(filtered_df == 'missing_value', True,
                            np.where(filtered_df == '', True,
                            np.where(filtered_df == 'N/A', True,
                            np.where(filtered_df == 'N\A', True,
                            np.where(filtered_df == 'NA', True,
                            np.where(filtered_df == 'N.A.', True,
                            np.where(filtered_df == 'NONE', True,
                            np.where(filtered_df == '.', True,
                            np.where(filtered_df.str.len() == 1, True,
                            np.where(filtered_df == '..', True, False))))))))))

    return(mydf)
```

Comment: forcing columns with `filtered_df = mydf[column].astype(str)` will cause integer values like `1` or `0` to be considered as missing values because of `filtered_df.str.len() == 1`

Comment: @SalvatoreDanieleBianco
That is true. But without `astype(str)` the function above will not be applicable to any other column than species, as none of them contains string data. It will throw the following exception `Can only use .str accessor with string values!`. So in any case a cast will be needed for those columns.

But of course the question remains whether it makes sense to apply the check for a lenght of 1 at all.